# How can you set colors per level in a Highcharts Sunburst chart?

Tags: highcharts, sunburst-diagram

Can you control colors per level in a Highcharts Sunburst chart? In this demo chart, is it possible to make the continents level and the sub-continent level, one 
single colour and the last level (countries) scaled colours?

```js
var data = [{
    'id': '0.0',
    'parent': '',
    'name': 'The World'
}, {
    'id': '1.3',
    'parent': '0.0',
    'name': 'Asia'
}, {
    'id': '1.1',
    'parent': '0.0',
    'name': 'Africa'
}, {
    'id': '1.2',
    'parent': '0.0',
    'name': 'America'
}, {
    'id': '1.4',
    'parent': '0.0',
    'name': 'Europe'
}, {
    'id': '1.5',
    'parent': '0.0',
    'name': 'Oceanic'
},

/* Africa */
{
    'id': '2.1',
    'parent': '1.1',
    'name': 'Eastern Africa'
},

{
    'id': '3.1',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Ethiopia',
    'value': 104957438
}, {
    'id': '3.2',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Tanzania',
    'value': 57310019
}, {
    'id': '3.3',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Kenya',
    'value': 49699862
}, {
    'id': '3.4',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Uganda',
    'value': 42862958
}, {
    'id': '3.5',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Mozambique',
    'value': 29668834
}, {
    'id': '3.6',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Madagascar',
    'value': 25570895
}, {
    'id': '3.7',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Malawi',
    'value': 18622104
}, {
    'id': '3.8',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Zambia',
    'value': 17094130
}, {
    'id': '3.9',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Zimbabwe',
    'value': 16529904
}, {
    'id': '3.10',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Somalia',
    'value': 14742523
}, {
    'id': '3.11',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'South Sudan',
    'value': 12575714
}, {
    'id': '3.12',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Rwanda',
    'value': 12208407
}, {
    'id': '3.13',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Burundi',
    'value': 10864245
}, {
    'id': '3.14',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Eritrea',
    'value': 5068831
}, {
    'id': '3.15',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Mauritius',
    'value': 1265138
}, {
    'id': '3.16',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Djibouti',
    'value': 956985
}, {
    'id': '3.17',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Réunion',
    'value': 876562
}, {
    'id': '3.18',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Comoros',
    'value': 813912
}, {
    'id': '3.19',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Mayotte',
    'value': 253045
}, {
    'id': '3.20',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Seychelles',
    'value': 94737
},

{
    'id': '2.5',
    'parent': '1.1',
    'name': 'Western Africa'
},

{
    'id': '3.42',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Nigeria',
    'value': 190886311
}, {
    'id': '3.43',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Ghana',
    'value': 28833629
}, {
    'id': '3.44',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Côte Ivoire',
    'value': 24294750
}, {
    'id': '3.45',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Niger',
    'value': 21477348
}, {
    'id': '3.46',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Burkina Faso',
    'value': 19193382
}, {
    'id': '3.47',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Mali',
    'value': 18541980
}, {
    'id': '3.48',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Senegal',
    'value': 15850567
}, {
    'id': '3.49',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Guinea',
    'value': 12717176
}, {
    'id': '3.50',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Benin',
    'value': 11175692
}, {
    'id': '3.51',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Togo',
    'value': 7797694
}, {
    'id': '3.52',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Sierra Leone',
    'value': 7557212
}, {
    'id': '3.53',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Liberia',
    'value': 4731906
}, {
    'id': '3.54',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Mauritania',
    'value': 4420184
}, {
    'id': '3.55',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'The Gambia',
    'value': 2100568
}, {
    'id': '3.56',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Guinea-Bissau',
    'value': 1861283
}, {
    'id': '3.57',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Cabo Verde',
    'value': 546388
}, {
    'id': '3.58',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha',
    'value': 4049
},

{
    'id': '2.3',
    'parent': '1.1',
    'name': 'North Africa'
},

{
    'id': '3.30',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Egypt',
    'value': 97553151
}, {
    'id': '3.31',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Algeria',
    'value': 41318142
}, {
    'id': '3.32',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Sudan',
    'value': 40533330
}, {
    'id': '3.33',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Morocco',
    'value': 35739580
}, {
    'id': '3.34',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Tunisia',
    'value': 11532127
}, {
    'id': '3.35',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Libya',
    'value': 6374616
}, {
    'id': '3.36',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Western Sahara',
    'value': 552628
},

{
    'id': '2.2',
    'parent': '1.1',
    'name': 'Central Africa'
},

{
    'id': '3.21',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Democratic Republic of the Congo',
    'value': 81339988
}, {
    'id': '3.22',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Angola',
    'value': 29784193
}, {
    'id': '3.23',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Cameroon',
    'value': 24053727
}, {
    'id': '3.24',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Chad',
    'value': 14899994
}, {
    'id': '3.25',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Congo',
    'value': 5260750
}, {
    'id': '3.26',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Central African Republic',
    'value': 4659080
}, {
    'id': '3.27',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Gabon',
    'value': 2025137
}, {
    'id': '3.28',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Equatorial Guinea',
    'value': 1267689
}, {
    'id': '3.29',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Sao Tome and Principe',
    'value': 204327
},

{
    'id': '2.4',
    'parent': '1.1',
    'name': 'South America'
},

{
    'id': '3.37',
    'parent': '2.4',
    'name': 'South Africa',
    'value': 56717156
}, {
    'id': '3.38',
    'parent': '2.4',
    'name': 'Namibia',
    'value': 2533794
}, {
    'id': '3.39',
    'parent': '2.4',
    'name': 'Botswana',
    'value': 2291661
}, {
    'id': '3.40',
    'parent': '2.4',
    'name': 'Lesotho',
    'value': 2233339
}, {
    'id': '3.41',
    'parent': '2.4',
    'name': 'Swaziland',
    'value': 1367254
},

/***********/

/* America */
{
    'id': '2.9',
    'parent': '1.2',
    'name': 'South America'
},

{
    'id': '3.98',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Brazil',
    'value': 209288278
}, {
    'id': '3.99',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Colombia',
    'value': 49065615
}, {
    'id': '3.100',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Argentina',
    'value': 44271041
}, {
    'id': '3.101',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Peru',
    'value': 32165485
}, {
    'id': '3.102',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Venezuela',
    'value': 31977065
}, {
    'id': '3.103',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Chile',
    'value': 18054726
}, {
    'id': '3.104',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Ecuador',
    'value': 16624858
}, {
    'id': '3.105',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Bolivia',
    'value': 11051600
}, {
    'id': '3.106',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Paraguay',
    'value': 6811297
}, {
    'id': '3.107',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Uruguay',
    'value': 3456750
}, {
    'id': '3.108',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Guyana',
    'value': 777859
}, {
    'id': '3.109',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Suriname',
    'value': 563402
}, {
    'id': '3.110',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'French Guiana',
    'value': 282731
}, {
    'id': '3.111',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Falkland Islands',
    'value': 2910
},

{
    'id': '2.8',
    'parent': '1.2',
    'name': 'Northern America'
},

{
    'id': '3.93',
    'parent': '2.8',
    'name': 'United States',
    'value': 324459463
}, {
    'id': '3.94',
    'parent': '2.8',
    'name': 'Canada',
    'value': 36624199
}, {
    'id': '3.95',
    'parent': '2.8',
    'name': 'Bermuda',
    'value': 61349
}, {
    'id': '3.96',
    'parent': '2.8',
    'name': 'Greenland',
    'value': 56480
}, {
    'id': '3.97',
    'parent': '2.8',
    'name': 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon',
    'value': 6320
},

{
    'id': '2.7',
    'parent': '1.2',
    'name': 'Central America'
},

{
    'id': '3.85',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Mexico',
    'value': 129163276
}, {
    'id': '3.86',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Guatemala',
    'value': 16913503
}, {
    'id': '3.87',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Honduras',
    'value': 9265067
}, {
    'id': '3.88',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'El Salvador',
    'value': 6377853
}, {
    'id': '3.89',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Nicaragua',
    'value': 6217581
}, {
    'id': '3.90',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Costa Rica',
    'value': 4905769
}, {
    'id': '3.91',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Panama',
    'value': 4098587
}, {
    'id': '3.92',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Belize',
    'value': 374681
},

{
    'id': '2.6',
    'parent': '1.2',
    'name': 'Caribbean'
},

{
    'id': '3.59',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Cuba',
    'value': 11484636
}, {
    'id': '3.60',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Haiti',
    'value': 10981229
}, {
    'id': '3.61',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Dominican Republic',
    'value': 10766998
}, {
    'id': '3.62',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Puerto Rico',
    'value': 3663131
}, {
    'id': '3.63',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Jamaica',
    'value': 2890299
}, {
    'id': '3.64',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Trinidad and Tobago',
    'value': 1369125
}, {
    'id': '3.65',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Guadeloupe',
    'value': 449568
}, {
    'id': '3.66',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Bahamas',
    'value': 395361
}, {
    'id': '3.67',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Martinique',
    'value': 384896
}, {
    'id': '3.68',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Barbados',
    'value': 285719
}, {
    'id': '3.69',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Saint Lucia',
    'value': 178844
}, {
    'id': '3.70',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Curaçao',
    'value': 160539
}, {
    'id': '3.71',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines',
    'value': 109897
}, {
    'id': '3.72',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Grenada',
    'value': 107825
}, {
    'id': '3.73',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Aruba',
    'value': 105264
}, {
    'id': '3.74',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'United States Virgin Islands',
    'value': 104901
}, {
    'id': '3.75',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Antigua and Barbuda',
    'value': 102012
}, {
    'id': '3.76',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Dominica',
    'value': 73925
}, {
    'id': '3.77',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Cayman Islands',
    'value': 61559
}, {
    'id': '3.78',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Saint Kitts and Nevis',
    'value': 55345
}, {
    'id': '3.79',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Sint Maarten',
    'value': 40120
}, {
    'id': '3.80',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Turks and Caicos Islands',
    'value': 35446
}, {
    'id': '3.81',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'British Virgin Islands',
    'value': 31196
}, {
    'id': '3.82',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Caribbean Netherlands',
    'value': 25398
}, {
    'id': '3.83',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Anguilla',
    'value': 14909
}, {
    'id': '3.84',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Montserrat',
    'value': 5177
},
/***********/

/* Asia */
{
    'id': '2.13',
    'parent': '1.3',
    'name': 'Southern Asia'
},

{
    'id': '3.136',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'India',
    'value': 1339180127
}, {
    'id': '3.137',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Pakistan',
    'value': 197015955
}, {
    'id': '3.138',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Bangladesh',
    'value': 164669751
}, {
    'id': '3.139',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Iran',
    'value': 81162788
}, {
    'id': '3.140',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Afghanistan',
    'value': 35530081
}, {
    'id': '3.141',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Nepal',
    'value': 29304998
}, {
    'id': '3.142',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Sri Lanka',
    'value': 20876917
}, {
    'id': '3.143',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Bhutan',
    'value': 807610
}, {
    'id': '3.144',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Maldives',
    'value': 436330
},

{
    'id': '2.11',
    'parent': '1.3',
    'name': 'Eastern Asia'
},

{
    'id': '3.117',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'China',
    'value': 1409517397
}, {
    'id': '3.118',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'Japan',
    'value': 127484450
}, {
    'id': '3.119',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'South Korea',
    'value': 50982212
}, {
    'id': '3.120',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'North Korea',
    'value': 25490965
}, {
    'id': '3.121',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'Taiwan',
    'value': 23626456
}, {
    'id': '3.122',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'Hong Kong',
    'value': 7364883
}, {
    'id': '3.123',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'Mongolia',
    'value': 3075647
}, {
    'id': '3.124',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'Macau',
    'value': 622567
},

{
    'id': '2.12',
    'parent': '1.3',
    'name': 'South-Eastern Asia'
},

{
    'id': '3.125',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Indonesia',
    'value': 263991379
}, {
    'id': '3.126',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Philippines',
    'value': 104918090
}, {
    'id': '3.127',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Vietnam',
    'value': 95540800
}, {
    'id': '3.128',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Thailand',
    'value': 69037513
}, {
    'id': '3.129',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Myanmar',
    'value': 53370609
}, {
    'id': '3.130',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Malaysia',
    'value': 31624264
}, {
    'id': '3.131',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Cambodia',
    'value': 16005373
}, {
    'id': '3.132',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Laos',
    'value': 6858160
}, {
    'id': '3.133',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Singapore',
    'value': 5708844
}, {
    'id': '3.134',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Timor-Leste',
    'value': 1296311
}, {
    'id': '3.135',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Brunei',
    'value': 428697
    // 'color': ''
},

{
    'id': '2.14',
    'parent': '1.3',
    'name': 'Western Asia'
},

{
    'id': '3.145',
    'parent': '2.14',
    'name': 'Turkey',
    'value': 80745020
}, {
    'id': '3.146',
    'parent': '2.14',
    'name': 'Iraq',
    'value': 38274618
}, {
    'id': '3.147',
    'parent': '2.14',
    'name': 'Saudi Arabia',
    'value': 32938213
}, {
    'id': '3.148',
    'parent': '2.14',
    'name': 'Yemen',
    'value': 28250420
}, {
    'id': '3.149',
    'parent': '2.14',
    'name': 'Syria',
    'value': 18269868
}, {
    'id': '3.150',
    'parent': '2.14',
    'name': 'Azerbaijan',
    'value': 9827589
}, {
    'id': '3.115',
    'parent': '2.10',
    'name': 'Kyrgyzstan',
    'value': 6045117
}, {
    'id': '3.116',
    'parent': '2.10',
    'name': 'Turkmenistan',
    'value': 5758075
},
/***********/

/* Europe */
{
    'id': '2.15',
    'parent': '1.4',
    'name': 'Eastern Europe'
},

{
    'id': '3.162',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Russia',
    'value': 143989754
}, {
    'id': '3.163',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Ukraine',
    'value': 44222947
}, {
    'id': '3.164',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Poland',
    'value': 38170712
}, {
    'id': '3.165',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Romania',
    'value': 19679306
}, {
    'id': '3.166',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Czechia',
    'value': 10618303
}, {
    'id': '3.167',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Hungary',
    'value': 9721559
}, {
    'id': '3.168',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Belarus',
    'value': 9468338
}, {
    'id': '3.169',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Bulgaria',
    'value': 7084571
}, {
    'id': '3.170',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Slovakia',
    'value': 5447662
}, {
    'id': '3.171',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Moldova',
    'value': 4051212
}, {
    'id': '3.172',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Cyprus',
    'value': 1179551
},

{
    'id': '2.16',
    'parent': '1.4',
    'name': 'Northern Europe'
},

{
    'id': '3.173',
    'parent': '2.16',
    'name': 'United Kingdom',
    'value': 66181585
}, {
    'id': '3.188',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Greece',
    'value': 11159773
}, {
    'id': '3.189',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Portugal',
    'value': 10329506
}, {
    'id': '3.190',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Serbia',
    'value': 8790574
}, {
    'id': '3.191',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Croatia',
    'value': 4189353
}, {
    'id': '3.192',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Bosnia and Herzegovina',
    'value': 3507017
}, {
    'id': '3.193',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Albania',
    'value': 2930187
}, {
    'id': '3.194',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Republic of Macedonia',
    'value': 2083160
}, {
    'id': '3.195',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Slovenia',
    'value': 2079976
}, {
    'id': '3.196',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Montenegro',
    'value': 628960
}, {
    'id': '3.197',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Malta',
    'value': 430835
}, {
    'id': '3.198',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Andorra',
    'value': 76965
}, {
    'id': '3.199',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Gibraltar',
    'value': 34571
}, {
    'id': '3.200',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'San Marino',
    'value': 33400
}, {
    'id': '3.201',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Vatican City',
    'value': 792
},

{
    'id': '2.18',
    'parent': '1.4',
    'name': 'Western Europe'
},

{
    'id': '3.202',
    'parent': '2.18',
    'name': 'Germany',
    'value': 82114224
}, {
    'id': '3.203',
    'parent': '2.18',
    'name': 'France',
    'value': 64979548
}, {
    'id': '3.204',
    'parent': '2.18',
    'name': 'Netherlands',
    'value': 17035938
}, {
    'id': '3.205',
    'parent': '2.18',
    'name': 'Belgium',
    'value': 11429336
}, {
    'id': '3.206',
    'parent': '2.18',
    'name': 'Austria',
    'value': 8735453
}, {
    'id': '3.207',
    'parent': '2.18',
    'name': 'Switzerland',
    'value': 8476005
}, {
    'id': '3.215',
    'parent': '2.20',
    'name': 'Solomon Islands',
    'value': 611343
}, {
    'id': '3.216',
    'parent': '2.20',
    'name': 'New Caledonia',
    'value': 276255
}, {
    'id': '3.217',
    'parent': '2.20',
    'name': 'Vanuatu',
    'value': 276244
},

{
    'id': '2.21',
    'parent': '1.5',
    'name': 'Micronesia'
},

{
    'id': '3.218',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Guam',
    'value': 164229
}, {
    'id': '3.219',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Kiribati',
    'value': 116398
}, {
    'id': '3.220',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Federated States of Micronesia',
    'value': 105544
}, {
    'id': '3.221',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Northern Mariana Islands',
    'value': 55144
}, {
    'id': '3.222',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Marshall Islands',
    'value': 53127
}, {
    'id': '3.223',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Palau',
    'value': 21729
}, {
    'id': '3.224',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Nauru',
    'value': 11359
},

{
    'id': '2.22',
    'parent': '1.5',
    'name': 'Polynesia'
},

{
    'id': '3.225',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'French Polynesia',
    'value': 283007
}, {
    'id': '3.226',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Samoa',
    'value': 196440
}, {
    'id': '3.227',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Tonga',
    'value': 108020
}, {
    'id': '3.228',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'American Samoa',
    'value': 55641
}, {
    'id': '3.229',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Cook Islands',
    'value': 17380
}, {
    'id': '3.230',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Wallis and Futuna',
    'value': 11773
}, {
    'id': '3.231',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Tuvalu',
    'value': 11192
}, {
    'id': '3.232',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Niue',
    'value': 1618
}, {
    'id': '3.233',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Tokelau',
    'value': 1300
}];

// Splice in transparent for the center circle
Highcharts.getOptions().colors.splice(0, 0, 'transparent');


Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        height: '100%'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'World population 2017'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source <href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)">Wikipedia</a>'
    },
    series: [{
        type: "sunburst",
        data: data,
        allowDrillToNode: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            format: '{point.name}',
            filter: {
                property: 'innerArcLength',
                operator: '>',
                value: 16
            }
        },
        levels: [{
            level: 1,
            levelIsConstant: false,
            dataLabels: {
                filter: {
                    property: 'outerArcLength',
                    operator: '>',
                    value: 64
                }
            }
        }, {
            level: 2,
            colorByPoint: true
        },
        {
            level: 3,
            colorVariation: {
                key: 'brightness',
                to: -0.5
            }
        }, {
            level: 4,
            colorVariation: {
                key: 'brightness',
                to: 0.5
            }
        }]

    }],
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: "",
        pointFormat: 'The population of <b>{point.name}</b> is <b>{point.value}</b>'
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sunburst.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Offical highcharts example here: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/sunburst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each level inherits the previous level's settings unless overwritten. So by simply setting the initial level's color, and removing all mention of color for the following levels, all levels will be that color. You would then need to set the last level to what you prefer. The levels definition would then look like this:

```
levels: [{
  level: 1,
  levelIsConstant: false,
  color: 'red',
  dataLabels: {
    filter: {
      property: 'outerArcLength',
      operator: '>',
      value: 64
    }
  }
}, {
  level: 4,
  colorByPoint: true
}]
```

```js
var data = [{
    'id': '0.0',
    'parent': '',
    'name': 'The World'
  }, {
    'id': '1.3',
    'parent': '0.0',
    'name': 'Asia'
  }, {
    'id': '1.1',
    'parent': '0.0',
    'name': 'Africa'
  }, {
    'id': '1.2',
    'parent': '0.0',
    'name': 'America'
  }, {
    'id': '1.4',
    'parent': '0.0',
    'name': 'Europe'
  }, {
    'id': '1.5',
    'parent': '0.0',
    'name': 'Oceanic'
  },

  /* Africa */
  {
    'id': '2.1',
    'parent': '1.1',
    'name': 'Eastern Africa'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.1',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Ethiopia',
    'value': 104957438
  }, {
    'id': '3.2',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Tanzania',
    'value': 57310019
  }, {
    'id': '3.3',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Kenya',
    'value': 49699862
  }, {
    'id': '3.4',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Uganda',
    'value': 42862958
  }, {
    'id': '3.5',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Mozambique',
    'value': 29668834
  }, {
    'id': '3.6',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Madagascar',
    'value': 25570895
  }, {
    'id': '3.7',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Malawi',
    'value': 18622104
  }, {
    'id': '3.8',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Zambia',
    'value': 17094130
  }, {
    'id': '3.9',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Zimbabwe',
    'value': 16529904
  }, {
    'id': '3.10',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Somalia',
    'value': 14742523
  }, {
    'id': '3.11',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'South Sudan',
    'value': 12575714
  }, {
    'id': '3.12',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Rwanda',
    'value': 12208407
  }, {
    'id': '3.13',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Burundi',
    'value': 10864245
  }, {
    'id': '3.14',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Eritrea',
    'value': 5068831
  }, {
    'id': '3.15',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Mauritius',
    'value': 1265138
  }, {
    'id': '3.16',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Djibouti',
    'value': 956985
  }, {
    'id': '3.17',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Réunion',
    'value': 876562
  }, {
    'id': '3.18',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Comoros',
    'value': 813912
  }, {
    'id': '3.19',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Mayotte',
    'value': 253045
  }, {
    'id': '3.20',
    'parent': '2.1',
    'name': 'Seychelles',
    'value': 94737
  },

  {
    'id': '2.5',
    'parent': '1.1',
    'name': 'Western Africa'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.42',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Nigeria',
    'value': 190886311
  }, {
    'id': '3.43',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Ghana',
    'value': 28833629
  }, {
    'id': '3.44',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Côte Ivoire',
    'value': 24294750
  }, {
    'id': '3.45',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Niger',
    'value': 21477348
  }, {
    'id': '3.46',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Burkina Faso',
    'value': 19193382
  }, {
    'id': '3.47',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Mali',
    'value': 18541980
  }, {
    'id': '3.48',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Senegal',
    'value': 15850567
  }, {
    'id': '3.49',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Guinea',
    'value': 12717176
  }, {
    'id': '3.50',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Benin',
    'value': 11175692
  }, {
    'id': '3.51',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Togo',
    'value': 7797694
  }, {
    'id': '3.52',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Sierra Leone',
    'value': 7557212
  }, {
    'id': '3.53',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Liberia',
    'value': 4731906
  }, {
    'id': '3.54',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Mauritania',
    'value': 4420184
  }, {
    'id': '3.55',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'The Gambia',
    'value': 2100568
  }, {
    'id': '3.56',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Guinea-Bissau',
    'value': 1861283
  }, {
    'id': '3.57',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Cabo Verde',
    'value': 546388
  }, {
    'id': '3.58',
    'parent': '2.5',
    'name': 'Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha',
    'value': 4049
  },

  {
    'id': '2.3',
    'parent': '1.1',
    'name': 'North Africa'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.30',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Egypt',
    'value': 97553151
  }, {
    'id': '3.31',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Algeria',
    'value': 41318142
  }, {
    'id': '3.32',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Sudan',
    'value': 40533330
  }, {
    'id': '3.33',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Morocco',
    'value': 35739580
  }, {
    'id': '3.34',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Tunisia',
    'value': 11532127
  }, {
    'id': '3.35',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Libya',
    'value': 6374616
  }, {
    'id': '3.36',
    'parent': '2.3',
    'name': 'Western Sahara',
    'value': 552628
  },

  {
    'id': '2.2',
    'parent': '1.1',
    'name': 'Central Africa'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.21',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Democratic Republic of the Congo',
    'value': 81339988
  }, {
    'id': '3.22',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Angola',
    'value': 29784193
  }, {
    'id': '3.23',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Cameroon',
    'value': 24053727
  }, {
    'id': '3.24',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Chad',
    'value': 14899994
  }, {
    'id': '3.25',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Congo',
    'value': 5260750
  }, {
    'id': '3.26',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Central African Republic',
    'value': 4659080
  }, {
    'id': '3.27',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Gabon',
    'value': 2025137
  }, {
    'id': '3.28',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Equatorial Guinea',
    'value': 1267689
  }, {
    'id': '3.29',
    'parent': '2.2',
    'name': 'Sao Tome and Principe',
    'value': 204327
  },

  {
    'id': '2.4',
    'parent': '1.1',
    'name': 'South America'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.37',
    'parent': '2.4',
    'name': 'South Africa',
    'value': 56717156
  }, {
    'id': '3.38',
    'parent': '2.4',
    'name': 'Namibia',
    'value': 2533794
  }, {
    'id': '3.39',
    'parent': '2.4',
    'name': 'Botswana',
    'value': 2291661
  }, {
    'id': '3.40',
    'parent': '2.4',
    'name': 'Lesotho',
    'value': 2233339
  }, {
    'id': '3.41',
    'parent': '2.4',
    'name': 'Swaziland',
    'value': 1367254
  },

  /***********/

  /* America */
  {
    'id': '2.9',
    'parent': '1.2',
    'name': 'South America'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.98',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Brazil',
    'value': 209288278
  }, {
    'id': '3.99',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Colombia',
    'value': 49065615
  }, {
    'id': '3.100',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Argentina',
    'value': 44271041
  }, {
    'id': '3.101',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Peru',
    'value': 32165485
  }, {
    'id': '3.102',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Venezuela',
    'value': 31977065
  }, {
    'id': '3.103',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Chile',
    'value': 18054726
  }, {
    'id': '3.104',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Ecuador',
    'value': 16624858
  }, {
    'id': '3.105',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Bolivia',
    'value': 11051600
  }, {
    'id': '3.106',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Paraguay',
    'value': 6811297
  }, {
    'id': '3.107',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Uruguay',
    'value': 3456750
  }, {
    'id': '3.108',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Guyana',
    'value': 777859
  }, {
    'id': '3.109',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Suriname',
    'value': 563402
  }, {
    'id': '3.110',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'French Guiana',
    'value': 282731
  }, {
    'id': '3.111',
    'parent': '2.9',
    'name': 'Falkland Islands',
    'value': 2910
  },

  {
    'id': '2.8',
    'parent': '1.2',
    'name': 'Northern America'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.93',
    'parent': '2.8',
    'name': 'United States',
    'value': 324459463
  }, {
    'id': '3.94',
    'parent': '2.8',
    'name': 'Canada',
    'value': 36624199
  }, {
    'id': '3.95',
    'parent': '2.8',
    'name': 'Bermuda',
    'value': 61349
  }, {
    'id': '3.96',
    'parent': '2.8',
    'name': 'Greenland',
    'value': 56480
  }, {
    'id': '3.97',
    'parent': '2.8',
    'name': 'Saint Pierre and Miquelon',
    'value': 6320
  },

  {
    'id': '2.7',
    'parent': '1.2',
    'name': 'Central America'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.85',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Mexico',
    'value': 129163276
  }, {
    'id': '3.86',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Guatemala',
    'value': 16913503
  }, {
    'id': '3.87',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Honduras',
    'value': 9265067
  }, {
    'id': '3.88',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'El Salvador',
    'value': 6377853
  }, {
    'id': '3.89',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Nicaragua',
    'value': 6217581
  }, {
    'id': '3.90',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Costa Rica',
    'value': 4905769
  }, {
    'id': '3.91',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Panama',
    'value': 4098587
  }, {
    'id': '3.92',
    'parent': '2.7',
    'name': 'Belize',
    'value': 374681
  },

  {
    'id': '2.6',
    'parent': '1.2',
    'name': 'Caribbean'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.59',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Cuba',
    'value': 11484636
  }, {
    'id': '3.60',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Haiti',
    'value': 10981229
  }, {
    'id': '3.61',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Dominican Republic',
    'value': 10766998
  }, {
    'id': '3.62',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Puerto Rico',
    'value': 3663131
  }, {
    'id': '3.63',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Jamaica',
    'value': 2890299
  }, {
    'id': '3.64',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Trinidad and Tobago',
    'value': 1369125
  }, {
    'id': '3.65',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Guadeloupe',
    'value': 449568
  }, {
    'id': '3.66',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Bahamas',
    'value': 395361
  }, {
    'id': '3.67',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Martinique',
    'value': 384896
  }, {
    'id': '3.68',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Barbados',
    'value': 285719
  }, {
    'id': '3.69',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Saint Lucia',
    'value': 178844
  }, {
    'id': '3.70',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Curaçao',
    'value': 160539
  }, {
    'id': '3.71',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines',
    'value': 109897
  }, {
    'id': '3.72',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Grenada',
    'value': 107825
  }, {
    'id': '3.73',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Aruba',
    'value': 105264
  }, {
    'id': '3.74',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'United States Virgin Islands',
    'value': 104901
  }, {
    'id': '3.75',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Antigua and Barbuda',
    'value': 102012
  }, {
    'id': '3.76',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Dominica',
    'value': 73925
  }, {
    'id': '3.77',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Cayman Islands',
    'value': 61559
  }, {
    'id': '3.78',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Saint Kitts and Nevis',
    'value': 55345
  }, {
    'id': '3.79',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Sint Maarten',
    'value': 40120
  }, {
    'id': '3.80',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Turks and Caicos Islands',
    'value': 35446
  }, {
    'id': '3.81',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'British Virgin Islands',
    'value': 31196
  }, {
    'id': '3.82',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Caribbean Netherlands',
    'value': 25398
  }, {
    'id': '3.83',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Anguilla',
    'value': 14909
  }, {
    'id': '3.84',
    'parent': '2.6',
    'name': 'Montserrat',
    'value': 5177
  },
  /***********/

  /* Asia */
  {
    'id': '2.13',
    'parent': '1.3',
    'name': 'Southern Asia'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.136',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'India',
    'value': 1339180127
  }, {
    'id': '3.137',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Pakistan',
    'value': 197015955
  }, {
    'id': '3.138',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Bangladesh',
    'value': 164669751
  }, {
    'id': '3.139',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Iran',
    'value': 81162788
  }, {
    'id': '3.140',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Afghanistan',
    'value': 35530081
  }, {
    'id': '3.141',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Nepal',
    'value': 29304998
  }, {
    'id': '3.142',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Sri Lanka',
    'value': 20876917
  }, {
    'id': '3.143',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Bhutan',
    'value': 807610
  }, {
    'id': '3.144',
    'parent': '2.13',
    'name': 'Maldives',
    'value': 436330
  },

  {
    'id': '2.11',
    'parent': '1.3',
    'name': 'Eastern Asia'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.117',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'China',
    'value': 1409517397
  }, {
    'id': '3.118',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'Japan',
    'value': 127484450
  }, {
    'id': '3.119',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'South Korea',
    'value': 50982212
  }, {
    'id': '3.120',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'North Korea',
    'value': 25490965
  }, {
    'id': '3.121',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'Taiwan',
    'value': 23626456
  }, {
    'id': '3.122',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'Hong Kong',
    'value': 7364883
  }, {
    'id': '3.123',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'Mongolia',
    'value': 3075647
  }, {
    'id': '3.124',
    'parent': '2.11',
    'name': 'Macau',
    'value': 622567
  },

  {
    'id': '2.12',
    'parent': '1.3',
    'name': 'South-Eastern Asia'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.125',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Indonesia',
    'value': 263991379
  }, {
    'id': '3.126',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Philippines',
    'value': 104918090
  }, {
    'id': '3.127',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Vietnam',
    'value': 95540800
  }, {
    'id': '3.128',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Thailand',
    'value': 69037513
  }, {
    'id': '3.129',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Myanmar',
    'value': 53370609
  }, {
    'id': '3.130',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Malaysia',
    'value': 31624264
  }, {
    'id': '3.131',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Cambodia',
    'value': 16005373
  }, {
    'id': '3.132',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Laos',
    'value': 6858160
  }, {
    'id': '3.133',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Singapore',
    'value': 5708844
  }, {
    'id': '3.134',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Timor-Leste',
    'value': 1296311
  }, {
    'id': '3.135',
    'parent': '2.12',
    'name': 'Brunei',
    'value': 428697
    // 'color': ''
  },

  {
    'id': '2.14',
    'parent': '1.3',
    'name': 'Western Asia'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.145',
    'parent': '2.14',
    'name': 'Turkey',
    'value': 80745020
  }, {
    'id': '3.146',
    'parent': '2.14',
    'name': 'Iraq',
    'value': 38274618
  }, {
    'id': '3.147',
    'parent': '2.14',
    'name': 'Saudi Arabia',
    'value': 32938213
  }, {
    'id': '3.148',
    'parent': '2.14',
    'name': 'Yemen',
    'value': 28250420
  }, {
    'id': '3.149',
    'parent': '2.14',
    'name': 'Syria',
    'value': 18269868
  }, {
    'id': '3.150',
    'parent': '2.14',
    'name': 'Azerbaijan',
    'value': 9827589
  }, {
    'id': '3.115',
    'parent': '2.10',
    'name': 'Kyrgyzstan',
    'value': 6045117
  }, {
    'id': '3.116',
    'parent': '2.10',
    'name': 'Turkmenistan',
    'value': 5758075
  },
  /***********/

  /* Europe */
  {
    'id': '2.15',
    'parent': '1.4',
    'name': 'Eastern Europe'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.162',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Russia',
    'value': 143989754
  }, {
    'id': '3.163',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Ukraine',
    'value': 44222947
  }, {
    'id': '3.164',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Poland',
    'value': 38170712
  }, {
    'id': '3.165',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Romania',
    'value': 19679306
  }, {
    'id': '3.166',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Czechia',
    'value': 10618303
  }, {
    'id': '3.167',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Hungary',
    'value': 9721559
  }, {
    'id': '3.168',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Belarus',
    'value': 9468338
  }, {
    'id': '3.169',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Bulgaria',
    'value': 7084571
  }, {
    'id': '3.170',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Slovakia',
    'value': 5447662
  }, {
    'id': '3.171',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Moldova',
    'value': 4051212
  }, {
    'id': '3.172',
    'parent': '2.15',
    'name': 'Cyprus',
    'value': 1179551
  },

  {
    'id': '2.16',
    'parent': '1.4',
    'name': 'Northern Europe'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.173',
    'parent': '2.16',
    'name': 'United Kingdom',
    'value': 66181585
  }, {
    'id': '3.188',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Greece',
    'value': 11159773
  }, {
    'id': '3.189',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Portugal',
    'value': 10329506
  }, {
    'id': '3.190',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Serbia',
    'value': 8790574
  }, {
    'id': '3.191',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Croatia',
    'value': 4189353
  }, {
    'id': '3.192',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Bosnia and Herzegovina',
    'value': 3507017
  }, {
    'id': '3.193',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Albania',
    'value': 2930187
  }, {
    'id': '3.194',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Republic of Macedonia',
    'value': 2083160
  }, {
    'id': '3.195',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Slovenia',
    'value': 2079976
  }, {
    'id': '3.196',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Montenegro',
    'value': 628960
  }, {
    'id': '3.197',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Malta',
    'value': 430835
  }, {
    'id': '3.198',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Andorra',
    'value': 76965
  }, {
    'id': '3.199',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Gibraltar',
    'value': 34571
  }, {
    'id': '3.200',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'San Marino',
    'value': 33400
  }, {
    'id': '3.201',
    'parent': '2.17',
    'name': 'Vatican City',
    'value': 792
  },

  {
    'id': '2.18',
    'parent': '1.4',
    'name': 'Western Europe'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.202',
    'parent': '2.18',
    'name': 'Germany',
    'value': 82114224
  }, {
    'id': '3.203',
    'parent': '2.18',
    'name': 'France',
    'value': 64979548
  }, {
    'id': '3.204',
    'parent': '2.18',
    'name': 'Netherlands',
    'value': 17035938
  }, {
    'id': '3.205',
    'parent': '2.18',
    'name': 'Belgium',
    'value': 11429336
  }, {
    'id': '3.206',
    'parent': '2.18',
    'name': 'Austria',
    'value': 8735453
  }, {
    'id': '3.207',
    'parent': '2.18',
    'name': 'Switzerland',
    'value': 8476005
  }, {
    'id': '3.215',
    'parent': '2.20',
    'name': 'Solomon Islands',
    'value': 611343
  }, {
    'id': '3.216',
    'parent': '2.20',
    'name': 'New Caledonia',
    'value': 276255
  }, {
    'id': '3.217',
    'parent': '2.20',
    'name': 'Vanuatu',
    'value': 276244
  },

  {
    'id': '2.21',
    'parent': '1.5',
    'name': 'Micronesia'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.218',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Guam',
    'value': 164229
  }, {
    'id': '3.219',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Kiribati',
    'value': 116398
  }, {
    'id': '3.220',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Federated States of Micronesia',
    'value': 105544
  }, {
    'id': '3.221',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Northern Mariana Islands',
    'value': 55144
  }, {
    'id': '3.222',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Marshall Islands',
    'value': 53127
  }, {
    'id': '3.223',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Palau',
    'value': 21729
  }, {
    'id': '3.224',
    'parent': '2.21',
    'name': 'Nauru',
    'value': 11359
  },

  {
    'id': '2.22',
    'parent': '1.5',
    'name': 'Polynesia'
  },

  {
    'id': '3.225',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'French Polynesia',
    'value': 283007
  }, {
    'id': '3.226',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Samoa',
    'value': 196440
  }, {
    'id': '3.227',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Tonga',
    'value': 108020
  }, {
    'id': '3.228',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'American Samoa',
    'value': 55641
  }, {
    'id': '3.229',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Cook Islands',
    'value': 17380
  }, {
    'id': '3.230',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Wallis and Futuna',
    'value': 11773
  }, {
    'id': '3.231',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Tuvalu',
    'value': 11192
  }, {
    'id': '3.232',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Niue',
    'value': 1618
  }, {
    'id': '3.233',
    'parent': '2.22',
    'name': 'Tokelau',
    'value': 1300
  }
];

// Splice in transparent for the center circle
Highcharts.getOptions().colors.splice(0, 0, 'transparent');


Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    height: '100%'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'World population 2017'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source <href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)">Wikipedia</a>'
  },
  series: [{
    type: "sunburst",
    data: data,
    allowDrillToNode: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    dataLabels: {
      format: '{point.name}',
      filter: {
        property: 'innerArcLength',
        operator: '>',
        value: 16
      }
    },
    levels: [{
      level: 1,
      levelIsConstant: false,
      color: 'red',
      dataLabels: {
        filter: {
          property: 'outerArcLength',
          operator: '>',
          value: 64
        }
      }
    }, {
      level: 4,
      colorByPoint: true
    }]

  }],
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: "",
    pointFormat: 'The population of <b>{point.name}</b> is <b>{point.value}</b>'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sunburst.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/g2jmsqrz/4/